# Can't connect to sendgrid from server (and iptables woes)

Tags: iptables

I'm getting timeouts when using `telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 587` on my VPS, but it works fine from my local ubuntu station..so I think there's some firewall issue.

I have a docker setup (yes that has some security implications with iptables) on my server, and tried opening outgoing traffic to port 587, but it's not working. I tried UFW first, but that was confusing as Docker opens ports and UFW says they aren't allowed, so I uninstalled UFW. There's a lot of ufw trash still ingering in my iptables it seems.

Can anyone give some tips what might be causing my connection timeouts and how to clean my iptables from empty ufw rules?

This is the iptables -L output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:submission

Chain DOCKER (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.4           tcp dpt:8000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.5           tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.8           tcp dpt:8000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.8           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.8           tcp dpt:http

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say it's working locally but not on your VPS, I think you should check about its having external internet allowed.

Docker container as defaults settings does not block external traffic from your host to the big internet.

I think the problem is on your Docker host machine.

Can you explain what OS you are running on your Docker, are you running on single-node or in Docker Swarm cluster mode and where did you host your VPS?

Comment: I'm running a bytemarksmtp docker container on ubuntu, but if I just telnet from the host machine (without being in a container) it doesn't work either. Any debug ideas? The webservices are working fine, and I can run apt update etc.

Comment: If its not working from the host-machine either its sound not like a Docker issue, you can try to disable the ufw firewall (not recommended in production) but its a easy way to find out of its a firewall issue or not. If its still not working i run out of ideas here.

Comment: Fixed it, it was a VPS setting in my provider that closed email ports